# Capital gains tax on profits from stock market in Germany

Tags: capital-gains-tax, germany

I was wondering whether there are any tax provisions on capital gains from stock trading in Germany dependent how long the stocks are held. can anyone please help me with that information ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All stocks bought after 2009 fall under a 25% flat tax ("Abgeltungssteuer") on all capital gains, exluding additional tax through the"Solidaritätszuschlag" and potential church tax. There are otherwise no tax provisions I know of.

Up to 801€ or 1602€ for couples of capital gains can be set as a tax-free "Sparer-Pauschbetrag".

If you save in a "Riester-Fondssparplan"-pension, which invests in stocks, you can get up to 2100€ tax free each year(depending on your income) and potentially additional cash from the state (up to 175€ per person, up to 300€ for each child). From it, you will get a set pension that you will have to tax at your income tax rate in retirement. Whether such a vehicle may be worth it depends on your income, age, family situation and (especially) the fees on the plan.